# Use jQuery plugins in Webpacker

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack, infinite-scroll, webpacker

I have a Rails 5 application with Webpacker.

I am trying to add Infinite scroll using its jQuery plugin but I keep getting:

> cars.js:20 Uncaught TypeError:
>   $(...).infiniteScroll is not a function

My cars.js file looks like:

```
import 'infinite-scroll'

$('.item').infiniteScroll({
      path: `.paginator--cars .next_page a`,
      append: `.car`,
      scrollThreshold: false,
      status: '.page-load-status',
      button: '.view-more-cars-button',
      history: 'push'
    });
```

My application.js file looks like:

```
import 'jquery/src/jquery'
import '../js/cars'
```

My environment.js file looks like:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

module.exports = environment

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
  })
)
```

Any ideas? This is bugging me so much?

Neil

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you don't need jQuery.

Yes, when using this package in the browser, it makes itself available as a jQuery plugin ([source](https://github.com/metafizzy/infinite-scroll/blob/master/dist/infinite-scroll.pkgd.js)).

But, when accessed via Node.js, such as when bundled in Webpack, jQuery is not necessary; this package makes itself available as an AMD or CommonJS export ([source](https://github.com/metafizzy/infinite-scroll/blob/master/js/index.js)).

A quick glance at the project indicates the proper usage for you in your `cars.js` file would be instead:

```js
import InfiniteScroll from 'infinite-scroll'

new InfiniteScroll('.item', {
  // options
})
```

I'd also assume wrapping the `new InifiteScroll(...)` expression in a `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {})` callback would make sense as well.